# Javascript XMLSerializer with CDATA instead of charachter escaping

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm using Mozilla's [JXON code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JXON) to convert an object to a DOM tree.
Then I use **XMLSerializer** to serialize to text.

```
var xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString( JXON.unbuild( object ) );
```

Works pretty well so far. My problem is that I have a URL as one value. The serializer **escapes** `http://example.org/?foo=bar&bar=foo` to `http://example.org/?foo=bar&amp;bar=foo` which makes it valid, but the server I'm sending this to cannot parse it. It is expecting a CDATA block at this point.

**How can I serialize this to `"<![CDATA[http://example.org/?foo=bar&bar=foo]]>` instead?**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4488t/

**EDIT**: I fixed my problem another way. Would still be interesting to know if CDATA is possible somehow.

Comment: *"but the server I'm sending this to cannot parse it"* - Fix the server, or stop sending it XML. Obviously it cannot deal with XML, and that's a problem you won't solve with using CDATA.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. I'll talk to the folks who implemented this horrible API ;)

Comment: Good luck. :) If they purpot to support XML then it's their job. It's not that it would be hard or anything; there's an XML API for every programming language under the sun. And if they hate XML so much they can switch to JSON.